# jquery masking image effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to replicate this effect - http://4091.co.uk/test/mask-test.swf - using jquery/css.

I tried using this wonderful plugin - http://almogbaku.github.io/imageMask - but it needs to work in IE8 and maybe IE7 and so it was scrapped due to its use of the canvas element.

I have white divs currently, set at angles, animating in and out but it's incredibly time consuming - is there a plugin which creates this kind of effect or is there a method that would work in the IEs?

Comment: Have you tried this one http://blog.rjzaworski.com/2011/03/masking-images-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: C.Hazelton - honestly, if I could get away with not having it in IE I would. It's been a bane in my life since 2003.

Fabi - I'll go check this out, you may just have saved my week!

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://modernizr.com/

Modernizr makes it work for every browser that doesn't support HTML5 or CSS3.